# Using colons in environment variables with rollup.js

Tags: javascript, frontend, rollupjs

I need to set an api path in an environment variable. According to rollup.js documentation the way to pass environment variables is:

```
rollup -c --environment VALUE:foo,ANOTHER_VALUE:bar
```

Note that rollup use colon to separate the key from the value. My problem is that my api path also include colons:

```
rollup -c --environment API_PATH:http://localhost:8000/api
```

I have the previous line inside `scripts` in my `package.json`. On `process.env.API_PATH` inside of `rollup.config.js` I only get `http` instead of `http://localhost:8000`. Enclosing the value with single quotes didn't work and escaping it with `\:` makes the `package.json` invalid. How can I pass values with colons in rollup.js?

Answer (score 0):

I answer this in gitter, but also putting this here for posterity. I don't know if there's a way to escape the `:` when using `--environment` but you could use something like the [`cross-env` package from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to handle this.

```sh
cross-env API_PATH=http://localhose:8000/api rollup --config
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and can't find solution so I just split the url on 3 parts:

```
ENV API_PROTOCOL="http"
ENV API_HOST="localhost"
ENV API_PORT=""
ENV API_BASE_PATH="/api"
```

Not the best approach but it works